Rebasing local branch with remote upstream branch
I forked a project on Git Hub and cloned that forked project in my local machine. So I have three git systems: one upstream, the original project, one origin, the forked project on GitHub, and one on the local machine.
I created a branch on my local machine and committed some changes to it, which I then pushed on the forked repo. And finally, I made a pull request for that on the original repo.
After some time, some guy's PR merged in the original repo, so I rebased my local repo with the upstream repo. Now, when I try to create a push on the origin repo, I get the error Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind...
What did I do wrong above? Another question: Will the origin branch be rebased if I rebase my local branch with the upstream branch?

You did the correct actions, and are looking at the expected effect of rebasing your work on top of someone else's.
To have a view of what happens, I recommend running in a terminal:
git log --oneline --graph my_branch origin/my_branch

you should have an illustration that, after being rebased, your local branch my_branch is not a fast forward update of origin/my_branch.

The expected fix is to force update your branch on your own repo:
git push --force-with-lease origin my_branch

The PR in the upstream repo will follow your updates.
